# Error in MYSQL Query while using IF statement with variable values

Tags: mysql

I am getting an error on executing this query in MYSQL. Can you please help me identify the issue. Here is the query.

```
IF ('"+ @[User::CrMgName] +"' IS NULL)
THEN
Update companies
  Set crm_id = '"+ @[User::crm_guid] +"'
Where TRIM(LOWER(company_directory_name)) = '"+ @[User::EquityStoryId] +"'

ELSE
Update companies
  Set cr_manager = '"+ @[User::CrMgName] +"',
crm_id = '"+ @[User::crm_guid] +"'
Where TRIM(LOWER(company_directory_name)) = '"+ @[User::EquityStoryId] +"'  
END IF
```

Comment: Please post the error

Comment: Hmm, what was the error message?

Comment: post the error to find how to solve it

Comment: Let me show us an error

Comment: @JoeTaras Thank you for your help. Error code is 42000 which is saying that their is a syntax error in my query. Nothing Else. Actually I am using this query in SSIS execute SQL task to update data in MySQL database.

Comment: @Fari: Please copy and paste the error. Is important the part of error about your line code or field or other further information. Error 42000 is generic

Comment: @JoeTaras Thank you for your interest. I have found the issue. Issue is, we can't use conditional statements in General MySQL Scripts so to use IF Else statements, I have to use Stored Procedure.

Comment: @Fari Ok, but if you want to use a conditional statement you can use CASE statement in your query. If you want I try to write your query with CASE statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After comments, the issue if represented by IF statement use in script.

So, the solutions are two:

1. (As Fari said): Use a stored procedure
2. Replace `IF` statement with `CASE` statement

For solution 2. try this:

```
UPDATE companies
SET crm_id = 
CASE 
   WHEN @[User::CrMgName] IS NULL THEN '"+ @[User::crm_guid] +"'
   ELSE'"+ @[User::crm_guid] +"'
END,
cr_manager = 
CASE
  WHEN @[User::CrMgName] IS NULL THEN cr_manager
  ELSE '"+ @[User::CrMgName] +"'
END
WHERE TRIM(LOWER(company_directory_name)) = '"+ @[User::EquityStoryId] +"'
```

Comment: Unfortunately Case statement is also not allowed in MySQL General Script.

Comment: @Fari: I've updated my answer. CASE statement is correct (I've committed an error in the update syntax), try again